# Excel Macro to Convert Cell Data to Multiple Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a big bunch of cells in Excel that look like the following:

FName LName, Loc JB

Abbreviations are bad, so: First Name, Last Name, Location, Job.

I need to move that so it looks like this:

```
FName LName || LOC || JB
```

Caveats:

1. Must remove the , after the name.
2. Must capitalize the location (it's 2 or 3 letters, inconsistently capitalized. I want to make them all caps).
3. JB is anywhere from 1 to 4 characters on the end. I just need to take that last bit and dump it in.
4. They're all separated by at least a space (the first has a comma and a space).

I'd like a macro to do this, because I have to do it with relative frequency, and doing 200 rows of this by hand is a pain. Any help?

Comment: Your example with abbreviations shows one comma. Your example without abbreviations shows three commas. Which is the format? Or is the format not consistent?

Comment: I've edited for consistency. Just 1 comma.

Comment: Locations and jobs... Can both of those have spaces in them? If so, by what logic are you able to easily tell them apart?

Comment: No, LOC and JB will be all together with no space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is a formula in the next column. If your values are in column A starting with cell A1, try:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)&" || "&UPPER(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(",",A1)+2)-FIND(",",A1)-2))&" || "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(",",A1)+2))
```

This formula takes everything to the left of the comma and adds `" || "`. Then it finds the next space starting its search two characters after the comma. Using that index it then can extract the location and make it upper case. Then again we add `" || "`. Then knowing the index of that space we can grab everything to the right to grab the job. This same logic can be applied in VBA but this is probably a quicker solution and easier to pass between computers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a macro.  You can do it with a series of right()'s left()'s mid()'s and find()'s.  Also need to use Upper() for the loc.

For instance, if your data is in column A, to get a column with first and last name in column B, in B1 you could use:

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)`

That'll return everything up to but not including the comma.  For Loc, assuming there's a comma between Loc and JB in C1 you'd use:

`=UPPER(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,FIND(",",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-FIND(" ",A1)-3))`

That'll return the uppercase version of the middle of the string, starting 2 chars after the first comma (so you don't get the space), and ending 2 less than the difference between the first and second commas.  If there's no comma, you could do a similar set of searches to find where that last space is.

The last IN d1 is:

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(",",A1)+2))`

edited after the clarification of commas and spaces.

Comment: I assumed the || was a new column marker.  If you actually want the vertical bars, use Mark's function.

Comment: This was actually what I was doing before. I was hoping for a quicker method, but thanks for taking the time to write it out.

Comment: Hard to believe there's anything much quicker than double clicking the bottom right corner of the box to have it fill in the entire column of data.  As Mark said, you could certainly put this logic into a VB script and map it to a button but the time you'd save clicking one button instead of double clicking hardly seems worth the invested time.  At any rate, good luck.